# Add months on date but gives me 12:00 AM in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
DateTime dtshow = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(3);
Deadline.Text = dtshow.ToLongDateString().ToString();
```

Jun 15, 2016 at 01:12 AM
Sep 15, 2016 at 12:00 AM

If I add 3 months in "June 15,2016 at 01:12AM" it must give me a result of "Sep 15, 2016 at 1:12 AM". I wonder why the result gives me 12:00AM.
Please help. thanks!

Comment: The `Date` property will "zero out" the time to midnight.  Just remove it.  On another note if you do want `DateTime.Now.Date` you can use `DataTime.Today` instead.  Also you should go to bed.

Comment: Cool! Now I can go to bed. Thanks! :D

Comment: Be aware of [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only selecting the date component:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(3)
              ^--- here
```

If you want both the date *and* the time component, use the original value instead of filtering it:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Date` call returns only the date portion, stripping the time. Try:

```
DateTime dtshow = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
```